# How to compile windows base program with eclipse cdt(using VIsual Studio compiler)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i'd like to compile (debugging if possible) windows program in eclipse cdt with microsoft copmiler.

It's better to support eclipse tool-chain (in eclipse cdt)

It's impossible to find this solution in google, except using mingw's make and Visual Studio Makefile..

Are there anyone to have solution with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Wascana](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/), an Eclipse/CDT distro targeted at Windows-development. Unfortunately the Windows-support is not complete; since it lacks a proper debugger.