# Using Eclipse CDT with VisualStudio compiler

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse-cdt

([similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566225/how-to-compile-windows-base-program-with-eclipse-cdtusing-visual-studio-compiler) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431815/how-to-convert-visualstudio-project-to-eclipse-cdt) asked, but no adequate answer yet)

Is there a way to use the Visual Studio compilation tools (`cl.exe`, `link.exe`) with Eclipse CDT? What I basically need is a parser for `cl.exe`'s error messages, and support for automatically generate makefiles that would use it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[vcmakefile4cdt](http://code.google.com/p/vcmakefile4cdt/) claims to generate project file for Eclipse CDT from Visual Studio project, however it looks a bit unmaintained (last commit in 2010).